# How to combine 'onKeypress' and 'onClick' event in a single function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, onkeypress

I know this kind of questions has been asked before but here I have a problem where I have to write a single function that will handle 'onkeypress' when enter key is pressed and 'onclick' function on mouse click.

```
handleClick = (event, url) => {
window.open(url);
};

handleEnterKey= (event, url) => {
var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (code === 13) {
window.open(url);
}
}

onClick={(event) =>
this.handleClickOnTraining(event)
}
onKeyPress={(event) =>
this.handleEnterKeyOnCards(event)
}
```

I want to combine these two into a single function like click or enterkey.
How can I combine both?Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a single function and call it on both onClick & onKeyPress..

```
function handleClickKeypress (event,url){

   var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
   if (code === 13) {
    window.open(url);
   }

   else {
     window.open(url);
   }

}
```

Comment: I tried this approach this is not working onkeypress will work, onclick will not work

Comment: while calling it how to call it? onkeypress or onclick?

Comment: onClick={handleClickKeypress (event,url)}

Comment: YOu need to have both event handlers,,

Comment: Hi..Are you able to call function

Comment: Yes,I am able to call the function checking